# I cannot open HTTPS web-page even with installed certificate on Mozilla

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I try to configure `Jmeter` on `Ubuntu` and I cannot open `HTTPS` web-page even with installed certificate on `Mozilla`, HSTS statement appears on web page.

**LOGS in Jmeter**

> 2019/07/10 15:07:12 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy: [35494] KeyStore for SSL loaded OK and put host 'safebrowsing.googleapis.com' in map with key (safebrowsing.googleapis.com)
> 2019/07/10 15:07:12 WARN  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy: [35494] Problem with SSL certificate for 'safebrowsing.googleapis.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
> 2019/07/10 15:07:12 WARN  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy: [35498] Problem with SSL certificate for 'incoming.telemetry.mozilla.org'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate

**HSTS**
[image]

**Certificate in Mozilla**
[image]

Comment: Try the same in your browser incognito mode

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29930)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you've visited the site previously and when you try to visit it once more via JMeter's [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) proxy Firefox doesn't let you in because the certificate has changed.

The solution is to [clear your browsing data](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/delete-browsing-search-download-history-firefox), if you manage to find the information relevant to the site - try to delete only the site's information only, otherwise proceed with full removal of everything since the beginning of the time.

You can also try [creating a new profile](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Multiple_profiles) however only above hint is guaranteed to work.

Check out [Recording HTTPS Traffic with JMeter's Proxy Server](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-https-traffic-jmeters-proxy-server/) article for more information

Answer (score 0):

Before start you need to make sure 2 things to check:

- "Start" button on the JMeter Proxy page. Seems obvious, I know, but
  better to check.
- Do you have any other server processes running on that machine on the port 8080? You can only have one process using port 8080. If you already have a process that uses port 8080, just change your proxy to some other port number like 9191 or something that is not in used, in both the JMeter setup and in your browser.

After this try some recording with just HTTP site Ex. http://blazedemo.com/.
see if that records. If that works, then you know that the problem is setting up HTTPS.

There are two solutions for this issue

**1. Turn off HTTPS Scanning:-** 
Every antivirus or security software allows us to turn off HTTPS scanning functionality. The option can be available by different names like

- Do not scan encrypted connections
- HTTPS Scanning
- Scan SSL

**2. Root CA Validity:-**

For older version, JMeter generates a Root CA valid only for 7 days. In this case, you can use update version or you can edit validity for CA certificate.

- Open **JMeter/bin/jmeter.properties** file in any text editor as sudo user.
- Search for below lines

> The default validity for certificates created by JMeter
>
> proxy.cert.validity=7

- Update certificates validity for 5000 days, change it to

> The default validity for certificates created by JMeter
>
> proxy.cert.validity=5000

**Note:** Before updating file details keep a few points in mind.

- Stop JMeter
- Change the jmeter.properties
- Delete any existing  /bin/ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt,

Answer (score 0):

Run jmeter as a superuser, temporary certificate will install by itself:

sudo jmeter

run a test or start a recording session and a popup window will appear notifying.